# Find a missing number in a list

Tags: prolog

Say I have a List `[2,1,4,5]`, I would like to have a predicate that returns 3 as the missing element.

```
missing([], []).
missing([H|T], R) :- missing([H|T], H, R).
missing([], _I, []).
missing([H|T], I, [I|R]) :-
    H =\= I,
    !,
    NextI is I + 1,
    missing([H|T], NextI, R).
missing([_|T], I, R) :-
    NextI is I + 1,
    missing(T, NextI, R).
```

but it doesnt work with unsorted lists.

Comment: congrats on reaching 15 rep! :) you now have the power to up vote the answers which you deem good, and accept answers which you deem provide solution to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

If your implementation doesn't work on unsorted lists, the easiest way to solve it is by sorting your input list before performing your algorithm.  You can do this by adding the [sort/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=sort/2) predicate to your current implementation.

```
missing([], []).
missing(Raw, R):-
    sort(Raw, [H|T]),
    missing([H|T], H, R).
missing([], _I, []).
missing([H|T], I, [I|R]):-
    H =\= I,
    !,
    NextI is I + 1,
    missing([H|T], NextI, R).
missing([_|T], I, R):-
    NextI is I + 1,
    missing(T, NextI, R).
```

Testing:

```
?- missing([1,2,6], M).
M = [3, 4, 5].

?- missing([1,2,6,-1], M).
M = [0, 3, 4, 5].

?- missing([-1, 5], M).
M = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].

?- missing([-1, 5, -3], M).
M = [-2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4].

?- missing([5, -3], M).
M = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4].
```

Seems to work.

Comment: @honey If you feel this answer is sufficient for the question, you should accept it: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask  This helps the entire community: it shows your query has been fulfilled, it allows people searching for similar questions to have an acceptable answer, it also shows that you care how this community works.